# How to distinct and merge objects from an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects.

```
[
  { _id: { year: 2020, month: 1 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 1 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 2 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 4 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 5 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 8 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 9 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 11 } }
]
```

I want to remove the duplicate year properties from the objects and push different month data in one array object.

I want to get below output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "month": [1]
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2019,
      "month": [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 11]
    }
  }
]
```

I have tried but cannot get the expected output:

```js
let arr = [
  { _id: { year: 2020, month: 1 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 1 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 2 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 4 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 5 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 8 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 9 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 11 } }
];

let newArr= []; 
    arr.forEach(function (item) { 
        let isMatch = newArr.filter(function (elem) {
            return elem._id.year === item._id.year 
        })
        if (isMatch.length == 0) {
            newArr.push(item)
        }
        else {
            newArr.find(x => x._id.year === item._id.year)._id.month.push(...item._id.month);
        }
    })
    console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
let input = [
  { _id: { year: 2020, month: 1 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 1 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 2 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 4 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 5 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 8 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 9 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 11 } }
];

let result = input.reduce((state, current) => {
   let prev = state.find(x => x._id.year === current._id.year);
   if(prev){
      prev._id.months.push(current._id.month);
   }
   else{
      state.push({_id: { year: current._id.year, months: [ current._id.month ] } });
   }
   return state;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First make an object indexed by year, whose values are the months found for that year so far, and push to an array for the year (creating if necessary) on every iteration. Afterwards, transform the object of arrays into your output structure:

```js
const input = [
  { _id: { year: 2020, month: 1 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 1 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 2 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 4 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 5 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 8 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 9 } },
  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 11 } }
];

const monthsByYear = {};
for (const { _id: { year, month } } of input) {
  if (!monthsByYear[year]) {
    monthsByYear[year] = [];
  }
  monthsByYear[year].push(month);
}
const output = Object.entries(monthsByYear).map(
  ([year, month]) => ({ _id: { year, month } })
);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use reduce and findIndex and check if the accumulator array contains that year, then just push the month

```js
let data = [{
    _id: {
      year: 2020,
      month: 1
    }
  },
  {
    _id: {
      year: 2019,
      month: 1
    }
  },
  {
    _id: {
      year: 2019,
      month: 2
    }
  },
  {
    _id: {
      year: 2019,
      month: 4
    }
  },
  {
    _id: {
      year: 2019,
      month: 5
    }
  },
  {
    _id: {
      year: 2019,
      month: 8
    }
  },
  {
    _id: {
      year: 2019,
      month: 9
    }
  },
  {
    _id: {
      year: 2019,
      month: 11
    }
  }
]

let newData = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let isYrPresent = acc.findIndex((item) => {
    return item._id.year === curr._id.year;
  });

  if (isYrPresent === -1) {
    acc.push({
      _id: {
        year: curr._id.year,
        month: [curr._id.month]
      }
    })
  } else {
    acc[isYrPresent]._id.month.push(curr._id.month)
  }


  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newData)
```